# Source code defined wide char strings and cross-platform

Tags: c, string, unicode, g++, widechar

Under Visual Studio source-code-defined strings like `L"abc"` result into a C-string with 2-bytes wide chars.

- What about Linux compilers ? Is it also possible to use the L"" syntax ?
- If yes, are the chars of the C-string linux wide chars (i.e 4-bytes wide) ?
- Is there a "cross-compiler" way to  define UCS-2 or UTF-16 encoded unicode strings ?

Thank you. :)

EDIT : Forgot to mention that I can't use C++11.

Comment: See the relevant part of the C11 Standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that i can't use C++11. I'll be stuck with VS2005 and g++ with whatever version is used by the android NDK.

Comment: C11 Standard is not C++! Anyway, the C99 Standard has less options for string literals, but `L"foo"` is accepted ( http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.4.5 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way to conveniently write UTF-16 string literals without using at least C11 or C++11 (where you can use `u"..."`).

The wide string syntax (`L"..."`) creates a `const wchar_t*` using an implementation-defined encoding. On Windows, this encoding is UTF-16; with GCC (using GNU's libc), this encoding is UTF-32.

The only safe and portable way to create UTF-16—or any UTF—strings (pre-C11/C++11) is to write them as integer arrays. For example:

```
const uint16_t str[] = { 0x24EA, 0x0 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However if i'm using regular char strings, can i get a common encoding with both compilers ? Does the encoding depend on the source file's encoding ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, un-prefixed literals (`"..."`) are implementation-defined as well—but you'll have to be working on a fairly esoteric platform to find anything other than ASCII being used.